# How to get state of transaction from ethereum blockchain via an API

Tags: solidity, web3js, etherscan, explorer-api

[image]
How to get state of transaction from ethereum blockchain via an API

is there any API to fetch the State of the transaction

Answer (score 0):

The web3 library is the usual way to do it!

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#gettransaction